# How to make typescript realise that `find` may return undefined?

Tags: typescript

Typescript does not seem to have any problem at all with the following code, though I expected it would not like attempting to access the `id` property of `x`.

I would expect `test` to have type `(IdObject | undefined)`, but it does not; typescript seems to be too trusting that `find` will always return something of the type of the array.

Is there a way to make typescript realise that `find` may return undefined?

```js
interface IdObject {
    id: number;
}

const data: IdObject[] = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
];

const ids = [1, 2, 5];

const findById: (id: number) => IdObject = id => data
    .find(x => x.id === id);

const test = ids.map(findById);

test.forEach(x => console.log(x.id));
```

[Here's the same code on the typescript playground, if it helps.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IdObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20data%3A%20IdObject%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%202%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%203%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ids%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%205%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20findById%3A%20(id%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20IdObject%20%3D%20id%20%3D%3E%20data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.find(x%20%3D%3E%20x.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20id)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20ids.map(findById)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atest.forEach(x%20%3D%3E%20console.log(x.id))%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Do you have strictNullChecks on ? It works as expected if that option is on in the playground

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That solves it, many thanks!